# How can i do DbProviderFactories in .Net Standard 2.0 project as my main Application is framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I have my main project in Framework 4.7.2 , and this project references a netStandard Library project which is a netstandard 2.0.

I need "DbProviderFactories" in the .Net Standard project.

like:

```
System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory fact = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providername);
```

I can Change the netStandard Project version to 2.1, which contains  DbProviderFactories, but netstandard 2.1 does not consume with framework 4.7.2

Is there any Other way I can do this.

Comment: did you ever found a workaround?